# Chrome extension - Background page and unread items

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm making my first chrome extension and i'm stuck just before the end.

I'm getting a response from a server in json, outputing the html, cache it in localstorage check if there's cache if not getting again from server and then displaying.

Now. In the background.js I need to check every 30 mins if there're updates in the json file on the server... if any display a Badge, once clicked remove badge till next time. but I don't know what to do. Because if I make a `setInterval` it hits the server and always display a badge even if there's nothing new. Can you guy help me build the js, please?

```
    <script>
    setInterval(function(){
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "!!!"});});
    }, 1800000);
    </script>
```

I've also tried this way, but nothing happens.

```
function getUnreadItems(callback) {
    $.ajax(..., function(data) {
        process(data);
        callback(data);
    });
}

function updateBadge() {
    getUnreadItems(function(data) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:data.unreadItems});
    });
}

var pollInterval = 1*60*60; // 60 min
var timerId;

function startRequest() {
    updateBadge();
    timerId = window.setTimeout(startRequest, pollInterval);
}

function stopRequest() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
}
```

background.js

```
onload='startRequest()'
```

Comment: I'm not a chrome developer, but i have to ask... in your functions above, I don't see any time comparisons. Are you checking/storing/comparing any timestamps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never reset the unread items to "read" on the server, so every time you will ping the server, it will reply with the same number and will thus display that number again.

So you can do a couple of things:

- when you click your button and reset the badge to 0, you can send a request to the server to mark all the items as read. Which request will of course depend on your server and what it accepts. That way, the unread count on the server will always be up to date and your extension can be very "stupid": whatever is returned by the server is the current number of unread items.
- if you can't do that, you'll have to save some information locally to your extension and figure out the unread count yourself. What I mean by that is that instead of just requesting the unread count you'll need to get information about the specific items like a unique ID. Then every time you poll the server for the list of items, you add the IDs to a list saved in `localStorage` for example (or `chrome.storage.sync`) with a `viewed` tag set to `false` if that ID is not known yet. The background script will then go through that list and count the number of items that have a `viewed` tag set to `false` and use that as an unread count. Whenever you open the popup, you go through your whole list and set the `viewed` tag to `true` for all your items.

I've done something similar for [an extension to get your Hulu playlist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/qulu-%E2%80%93-your-hulu-queue/iggfkakbafpkgjaocfjaoehcclhcjckb?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). I did the first option when I delete a video from your playlist, so that it's removed locally and on the server as well. And I did the second option because I wanted to show a count for new videos, but Hulu doesn't keep track of that. (it knows played and unplayed, but not "you've been notified that this new video is available" which I wanted.

See in particular, [this section](https://github.com/Timothee/Qulu/blob/master/background.js#L68-73):

```
// Testing that it's the first time I'm seeing this show
if (show_ids.indexOf(new_show.id) == -1) {
    new_shows_number++;
    new_show.seen = "no";
} else {
    new_show.seen = "yes";
}
```

Here `show_ids` is the list of IDs I've already saved and marked as viewed locally. If `new_show.id` is not in this list, that means it's an unviewed item.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, sir. I think the second case will work for me. I'm able to get the unique ids and save them in localStorage, it becomes a super long line of numbers, but if the json file changes that line will update too. so I save them in localStorage with my popup.js then in background.js I do something like this: http://pastebin.com/udnMGHfX do you think it will work?

Comment: What are you trying to do on line 5 `var htmlIds = value.id`? It looks like you want to concatenate the IDs? Like `htmlIds += value.id`? If that's the case, you should first put `var htmlIds = '';` out side the `$.getJSON()` block. Checking a concatenated string with a saved string is fragile because it wouldn't work if the returned IDs are not ordered in the same way. You can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to handle objects. The former when you save to `localStorage` and the latter when you want to use it.

Comment: Then you probably should create an array of the saved/read IDs and look for the new on in it. This way, the order sent by the server doesn't matter. Plus, it will be much cleaner to manipulate real objects rather than a string. That's what I've done in Qulu too.

Comment: yeah, you're right. Thank you again you've opened me a new world, hahaha. will also check you Qulu extension to see what I can do.